# Result matrix where each entry is a vector of varying size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 128 X 8192 matrix. I have split it into cell arrays of size 1X64 each using :

C = mat2cell(input_matrix, repmat(1,[1 128]), repmat(64,[1 128]));

Now I need to pass each of these cell arrays to an function say 'fn_X'. This function returns an array of varying sizes. I need the output for each of the cell arrays passed to be stored in a result matrix. I used the following code :

```
for(irl = 1 : 128)
        for(jrl = 1 : 128)
            Output_matrix(irl,jrl) = fn_X(C{irl,jrl});
         end
end
```

This gave me an error 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.'

I then tried it in a column matrix using the following code :

```
king = 1;
    for(irl = 1 : 128)
        for(jrl = 1 : 128)
            Output_matrix(king) = fn_X(C{irl,jrl});
            king = king + 1;
        end
    end
```

This gave me an error 'In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.'

I also tried using cell array assignment using the following code :

```
king = 1;
for(irl = 1 : 128)
    for(jrl = 1 : 128)
        Output_matrix(king) = fn_X(C{irl,jrl});
        king = king + 1;
    end
end
```

This gave an error 'Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.'

Any suggestions on how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your code is that should use curly brackets on the left side of the assignment:

```
king = 1;
for irl = 1 : 128
    for jrl = 1 : 128
        Output_matrix{king} = fn_X(C{irl,jrl});
        king = king + 1;
    end
end
```

But this likely **not** the right way to do this. This is not the "style" of the language, the way that makes sense is to vectorize which will probably require `fn_X` handle this itself.

Alternatively, you can also do it with the much simpler (and often faster):

```
Output_matrix = cellfun (@fn_X, C, "UniformOutput", false);
```